# How do I link to Google Maps with a particular longitude and latitude?

Tags: html, google-maps

I have a small application that gives the current location: longitude and latitude.
Now I have to browse to google maps with the longitude and latitude.
Please suggest how I can do this.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

This schema has changed again (23rd October 2018). See [Kushagr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52943975/73488) for the latest.

This for a map with the marker (via [aaronm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295574/aaronm)'s comment):

<s>https://www.google.com/maps/?q=-15.623037,18.388672</s>

For an older example (no marker on this one):

<s>https://www.google.com/maps/preview/@-15.623037,18.388672,8z</s>

The oldest format:

<s>http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=-15.623037,18.388672&spn=65.61535,79.013672</s>

Comment: Is there somewhere information about the new format? Particularly, Internet is full of examples of old format and it is hard to Google (sic) the new format from all the noise.

Comment: The "new" format above does not include a marker, if you use this format it works - https://www.google.com/maps/?q=<lat>,<long>  eg: https://www.google.com/maps/?q=-15.623037,18.388672

Comment: Is there a way to specify the map type (hybrid, road, etc)?

Comment: thanks. is it possible to show a pin on custom location?

Comment: @pixparker See AaronM response above using google.com/maps/?q=<lat>,<long>   Also note there is no option here for zoom.

Comment: New best answer as per @Kushagr Arora's answer is https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=<lat>,<lng>

Answer (score 511):

The best way is to use `q` parameter so that it displays the map with the point marked. eg.:

```
https://maps.google.com/?q=<lat>,<lng>
```

Comment: @WareNinja do you know how to combine directions from/to with this?

Comment: How do you add the zoom parameter?

Comment: Thanks, this also makes Citymapper understand the link in case this link is inside an app

Comment: How can i create a shortcut for that URL ?

Comment: @Razgriz you should "z" parameter with a int value like maps.google.com?z=15

Comment: In case anyone is looking for the Google Earth equivalent, here it goes: `https://earth.google.com/web/@<lat>,<lng>`

Answer (score 196):

As of today (1st November, 2020), Google provided a provision of Universal URL which works quite efficiently on cross-platforms and thus, Google recommends this method.

Syntax: `https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=<lat>,<lng>`

Example :
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=28.6139,77.2090
(New Delhi, India)

[Documentation/Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide).

Comment: The [old URL format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme) still applies if you need features not available in the new one. Both formats are called "Universal Links", even though some don't work on Android. I guess Google subscribes to multiverse theory. :-)

Comment: I can confirm this is still valid as of 18th February 2021

Comment: I can confirm this works well for browser and android. On android it's triggers both the browser or the maps application as options to select to resolve the uri.

Answer (score 135):

As of today (2014/09/23), I've found that to get marker on exact place (not an approximation) you can use:

```
http://www.google.com/maps/place/49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796
```

Additionally, if you want to specify map center and zoom:

```
http://www.google.com/maps/place/49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796/@49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796,17z
```

If you want to use satellite map type, then append `/data=!3m1!1e3`

```
http://www.google.com/maps/place/49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796/@49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796,17z/data=!3m1!1e3
```

And If you want terrain view of the map, then append `/data=!3m1!4b1`

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796/@49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796,17z/data=!3m1!4b1
```

Comment: Any idea how to add the map type (hybrid, etc)?

Comment: @Redtopia, see my updated answer for satellite map type.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what that data variable means or how to interpret it? Also, are there any docs that you know about that describe this new linking scheme?

Comment: @Redtopia, it is just an experimental knowledge. Actually, I had to try several URL parameters to find an answer for you. I haven't found no such documentation. Sorry!

Comment: @Pogo19 is there a way to generate a google link with the nearby restaurants  like http://maps.google.com/?q=<lat>,<lng> would show me the location corresponding to the lat , long along with that can i also pass in some parameter to locate the nearby restaurants as well something like http://maps.google.com/?q=<lat>,<lng> & nearBy = restaurant

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot Try something like this: `http://www.google.com/maps/search/restaurant/@49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796,17z`

Comment: @Pogo19 Thanks a lot for your response.it is giving me a specific restaurant , i wanted the nearby restaurants for the particular lat long that i provide.

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot Try to change the search string, that is `/restaurant/` in my previous example URL.

Comment: It's February 2016 and it appears that this method still works. Well done.

Comment: @gmeben As long as Google Maps don't change it, it will work :)

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki It is the second example:
`http://www.google.com/maps/place/49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796/@49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796,17z`

Comment: Thank you! there you just mentioned map center & zoom, not marker, so I did not test it

Comment: This does not work anymore as of today. Here is the current description by google how to build links: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Comment: August 2020 and these all work on Chrome browser on Windows.

Answer (score 44):

If you want to open Google Maps in a browser:

`http://maps.google.com/?q=<lat>,<lng>`

To open the Google Maps app on an iOS mobile device, use the [Google Maps URL Scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme?hl=en):

`comgooglemaps://?q=<lat>,<lng>`

To open the Google Maps app on Android, use the [geo: intent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents):

`geo:<lat>,<lng>?z=<zoom>`

Comment: You can also use "google.navigation:q=latitude,longitude" to start immediately the navigation with google maps app, but does not work with some gps apps. The more generic is "geo:<lat>,<lng>?q=<lat>,<lng>(Label,Name)" as referred ojus kulkarni em previous comment (the parameters force to show the marker, helping to navigate)

Answer (score 23):

It´s out of the scope of the question, but I think it might be also interesting to know how to link to a route. The query would look like this:

```
https://www.google.es/maps/dir/'52.51758801683297,13.397978515625027'/'52.49083837044266,13.369826049804715'
```

Answer (score 19):

**These are URLs that work:**

`http://maps.google.com/?q=<LAT>,<LNG>`

`https://maps.google.com/?q=<LAT>,<LNG>&ll=<LAT>,<LNG>&z=18`

`https://www.google.com/maps/@<LAT>,<LNG>,16z`

`https://maps.google.com/?q=<LAT>,<LNG>&z=16`

**Although (for avid readers) This is the latest from google (August 22 2017):**

[Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide)
[Maps URLs with map display](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#map-action)
[Maps URLs with search action](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#search-action)

**From google**

> **Search**: When searching for a specific place, the resulting map puts a pin in the specified location and displays available place details.
>
> **Important**: The parameter api=1 identifies the version of Maps URLs this URL is intended for. This parameter is required in every request. The only valid value is 1. If api=1 is NOT present in the URL, all parameters are ignored and the default Google Maps app will launch, either in a browser or the Google Maps mobile app, depending on the platform in use (for example, https://www.google.com/maps).

Answer (score 18):

This works too:

```
https://www.google.pl/maps/@<lat>,<lon>,<zoom>z
```

[Example](https://www.google.pl/maps/@51.5088233,-0.1296787,13z).

With pointer:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/<lat>,<lon>/@<lat>,<lon>,<zoom>z
```

[Example](https://www.google.com/maps/search/51.5088233,-0.1296787/@51.5088233,-0.1296787,13z).

Answer (score 9):

To open the google maps app in android:-

```
geo:<lat>,<lng>?z=<zoom>
```

open app with marker for give location:-

```
geo:<lat>,<lng>?q=<lat>,<lng>(Label,Name)
```

open google map in ios:-

```
comgooglemaps://?q=<lat>,<lng>
```

open google maps in browser with following parameters:-

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=<lat>,<lng>
```

- `z` is the zoom level (1-21)
- `t` is the map type ("**m**" map, "**k**" satellite, "**h**" hybrid, "**p**" terrain, "**e**" GoogleEarth)
- `q` is the search query

Answer (score 7):

Using the query parameter won't work, Google will try to approximate the location.

The location I want : http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=43.7920533400153,6.37761393942265

The approximate location (west of the actual location) : http://maps.google.com/?q=43.7920533400153,6.37761393942265

Answer (score 5):

say easily `http://www.google.com/maps/place/lat,lng` format

sample url:

http://www.google.com/maps/place/30.364124,48.227034

Answer (score 4):

To get your current location as start point you need to use this URL:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Current+Location&destination=<latitude>,<longitude>
```

You can fill up the destination parameter with the address, name or latitude and longitude values.

Comment: thanks, that's what I need

Answer (score 3):

Open the following url with the latitude and longitude  and zoom level.

https://maps.google.com/?q=23.22,88.32&z=8

Answer (score 0):

Find your location in the Google Earth program, and click the icon "View in Google Maps". The URL bar in your browser will show the URL you need.

Answer (score 0):

Open google map and show URL schemes location and location pin

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"https://maps.google.com/?q=\(dicLocation.stringValueForKey("latitude")),\(dicLocation.stringValueForKey("longitude")),15z")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a dir with travel mode = walking

```
https://www.google.es/maps/dir/'52.51758801683297,13.397978515625027'/'52.49083837044266,13.369826049804715'/data=!4m2!4m1!3e2
```