# Url to a google maps page to show a pin given a latitude / longitude?

Tags: html, google-maps

Is there some url I can construct with a latitude,longitude pair that will lead me directly to a google maps page to visualize that location?

For example, the following pseudocode:

```
var lat = 43.23;
var lng = 114.08;

var url = 'http://google.com/maps/bylatlng?lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng';

print 'click here to see this location in google maps!: <a href="' + url + '">go</a>';
```

Something like that?

Thanks

Comment: Now here's *my* question:  is there a way to display multiple teardrops, or even a track with just a url?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=24.197611,120.780512

Some more info on the query parameters available [at this location](http://alvarestech.com/temp/routeconverter/RouteConverter/navigation-formats/src/main/doc/googlemaps/Google_Map_Parameters.htm)

Here's another link to an [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801732/how-do-i-link-to-google-maps-with-a-particular-longitude-and-latitude)

Comment: You can control the zoom by adding &z=<zoom level> to the end of that url (e.g. http://maps.google.com/maps?q=24.197611,120.780512&z=18).

Comment: Try this: http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters

Comment: @JonathanMcIntire the ability to set the zoom level like that doesn't seem to work any more; for your link it always seems to default it to zoom level 17 now.  Any ideas on how to control this?

Answer (score 25):

From my notes:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=37.4185N+122.08774W+(label)&ll=37.419731,-122.088715&spn=0.004250,0.011579&t=h&iwloc=A&hl=en

Which parses like this:

```
    q=latN+lonW+(label)     location of teardrop

    t=k             keyhole (satelite map)
    t=h             hybrid

    ll=lat,-lon     center of map
    spn=w.w,h.h     span of map, degrees
```

iwloc has something to do with the info window.  hl is obviously language.

See also: http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters

Comment: A bit off-topic but maybe still helpful for those who would like to specify a label/title/name for the marker on the Google Maps iOS app: while `q=lat,long+(My%20custom%20location%20name)` does no longer seem to work for the Google Maps web site, it does currently (still) work on their iOS app.

Comment: Thank you. Its works! Alson I add &z=10 for zooming in your example
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=37.4185N+122.08774W+(label)&ll=37.419731,-122.088715&spn=0.004250,0.011579&t=h&iwloc=A&hl=en&z=12