# Create Google Maps links based on coordinates

Tags: google-maps, hyperlink, coordinates, share

How can I create Google Maps links based on coordinates? Their new basic share urls contain a lot of parameters, for example:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Vetlanda,+Sweden/@57.4217311,15.0849255,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x465758d912d321b5:0x55675191e550be84?hl=en

Any ideas? Not looking to embed but just to create external links that can be shared.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Why not  `https://www.google.com/maps/place/lat,lng`
I think this is the simplest way

https://www.google.com/maps/place/49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796

Comment: is it possible to add a zoom level ?

Comment: @StanSokolov  yes  should be possibile adding to the url  eG.   &zoom=13 or &z=9

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @scaisEdge. I'm looking for a solution if there's anyway for me to use the same URL you provided and open a native apps such as google MAP or IOS maps hijacking the locations for "Get Directions" purposes. 

Is there a quick way to do this you can suggest?

Comment: you can easly  .. use the lat, lng  parameter  accessing as  GET parameter and the eval server side the content  .. try inspect the url content server side

Comment: @Cole128  jus add  you zoomLevel and z  eg: http://www.google.com/maps/place/49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796,10z

Comment: @scaisEdge That link doesn't work for me, it doesn't actually bring me to the coordinates.

Comment: @Cole128  i just copy the link and work  ..  be sure you have proper value lat, lng,zoomz eg: 45.00, 10.00, 13z

Comment: I opened it with a right click. It works for you? It fails in both Chrome and Firefox for me.

Comment: Yes  .. i used  firefox, opera, chrome   and wok  ..  very well. both with right click of copying  ..  and pasting

Comment: eventually try use this sintax  based on place (move the map to the nearest place) with zoom www.google.com/maps/place/45°28'04.8"N+10°06'54.5"E/@45.468,10.1129502,10z

Answer (score 35):

The currently accepted answer ends up adding an additional history entry in browsers at the moment as Google Maps redirects to a different URL format.

To avoid that extra entry in the browser's history, [use the official Maps API url](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#search-action):

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=latitude,longitude
```

This will display a marker at the latitude, longitude location as well.

If you only want to [center the map (and not display a marker), use the map action](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#map-action):

```
https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=map&center=latitude,longitude
```

Comment: Does this support setting the zoom level?

Comment: @Raj You can append `&zoom=<zoom level>` to the map action as shown in the last example (i.e. after `center=...`.

Comment: Is there a link which includes both the marker and the zoom level?

Comment: In that case you'll have to use the `/place/` url which require you to format one set of the coordinates in degrees/minute/seconds format as far as I can tell: https://www.google.com/maps/place/xx%C2%B0xx'xx.x%22N+yy%C2%B0yy'yy.y%22E/@xx.xxx,yy.yyy,13z/

Answer (score 31):

According to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5807150/3200341), you can use following url

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=24.197611,120.780512

to show a pin.

Comment: except it shows side panel I just wanted to embed the map in an inline frame or div ! would it be possible to open map but with side panel collapsed.

Comment: @Banzy this still works, just took this scrennshot of the url in the post: https://i.imgur.com/flQa6dm.png

Answer (score 17):

- Working in 2022
- No sidebar
- Url doesnt change
- Zoom included

Syntax:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/@{lat},{long},{zoom}z
```

Example:

https://www.google.com/maps/@51.123,10.123,15z

Answer (score 6):

The simple and best way is to use as follows:-

```
https://maps.google.com/?q=LATITUDE-VALUE,LONGITUDE-VALUE
```