# How to create a link/url of current location (google map v2, android)

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to create an app which sends a text message with user location in the form of url so that receiver can access the location of user using browser or google map(if install on user device)..

i am able to extract longi lati and address of the user .. but i want to know how to convert them into url..

For example:

1. user send the message by clicking send button (a location will be send in the form of url)
2. receiver get the message (which contains url).. by just clicking url he will be redirected to browser or google map application.. and receiver can view current location of sender.

So i just want to know how to create a url of our current location.. it will be more helpful if you can share me some kind of link or code of generating url.

Comment: https://maps.google.com/maps?q=33.8869,35.5131

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801732/how-do-i-link-to-google-maps-with-a-particular-longitude-and-latitude

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate an online link to a full screen map using an online application like [linkonmap.com](http://www.linkonmap.com)

You can create in seconds comprehensive and short links not to an address but even to a specific location on google map. The person which will receive the link may calculate even the shortest route starting between his location and yous (destination).

Comment: Link is dead. Try not to use links in your answers, but describe them instead.