# Google Maps V3 Show Map on Google Maps Link

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using a javascript Google Maps V3 to show the location of places I have on my site, I can only offer a small view on my site so anyone who wants to see the larger map on google should either click on the Google icone on the bottom left, or in some cases I saw a link/button on the map stating "click to show on Google Maps".

So my question is how to show the link/button on my map that can open the same location on google maps site.

Answer (score 0):

Google map provides an option to customize the link by adding some parameters for viewing map.

**You can get the list of parameters here:** 
http://alvarestech.com/temp/routeconverter/RouteConverter/navigation-formats/src/main/doc/googlemaps/Google_Map_Parameters.htm

You'll need to pass the parameters to the link.

**Example:** https://www.google.com.au/maps/preview/@,,

You can also refer this post for more details: [How do I link to Google Maps with a particular longitude and latitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801732/how-do-i-link-to-google-maps-with-a-particular-longitude-and-latitude)

Comment: Thanks but update your code with this link https://www.google.com.au/maps/preview/@<latitude>,<longitude>,<zoom level>z as your link is not working anymore with google