# Send latitude-longitude argument to Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following code:

```
function initialize(lat, lng) {
                    window.open("https://maps.google.com/?q=<lat>,<lng>");
                }
```

Can anyone tell me how to send the lat/lng arguments to Google Maps in the URL?

EDIT - Right now, the values being sent to Maps are "lat" and "lng", NOT their actual values such as 5 and 10. Can someone tell me how to send their actual values in the call to Maps?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801732/how-do-i-link-to-google-maps-with-a-particular-longitude-and-latitude)?

Comment: @VadimGremyachev Suppose my lat and lng values are 5 and 10, respectively. I want to pass in those values as parameters to Google Maps. Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Example**

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="map-btn" data-lat="41.8911684" data-lng="12.507724100000019"> Show Map </a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $('.map-btn').click(function(event) {
      var lat = $(this).data('lat');
      var lng = $(this).data('lng');
      showMap(lat,lng);
    });
});

function showMap(lat,lng){
   var url = "https://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat + "," + lng;
   window.open(url);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/51nkmncd/)