# Can you use anything else besides mailto and tel in href attribute of an <address /> tag?

Tags: html

I'm rewriting an old static website and had to implement some contact info. For that I used the `<address>` tag, where I saw that you could further annotate an e-mail address by adding `mailto:` to the href attribute so that it opens the default mail program and a phone number by adding `tel:`, which when clicked prompts the user whether or not they want to call the person (I have my Android synced with Chrome so it asked me if I want to call that number via my Android).

My question is whether there are more of these special href annotations (ex. for opening coords in Google maps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uri schemes are listed here https://www.w3.org/wiki/UriSchemes

To make your web page open google maps with coordinates you don’t need a special scheme. See this SO [How do I link to Google Maps with a particular longitude and latitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801732/how-do-i-link-to-google-maps-with-a-particular-longitude-and-latitude)